# Media queries min-width : 0?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, tablet

Right now I'm using these queries:

```
/*Desktop and laptops*/
media only screen and (min-width : 1224px)

/*Tablet landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape)

/*Tablet Portrait*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
```

I was wondering if I should change the first query to `(min-width : 0px)`

As you can see the other queries only work with landscape or portrait mode. 
So if I make my screen smaller on laptop/desktop it doesn't use any CSS anymore.

What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: Ofcourse, the first media query wont hit unless your screen width is greater than 1224px. If you want to make it your default styles, remove the first media query and include that CSS in your default CSS file without any media directive like normal CSS. My suggestion would be to include the media queries for known screen widths. that are commonly used.

Comment: Add a MQ for `max-width: 767px` and you're done? (is 1**2**24px a typo? Should be 1024px or there's a gap)

Comment: Should I remove the "device" part? So the queries still works on smaller desktops/Laptops? 

I've got my MQ's straight out of: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

And that is what I was wondering too, there are a lot of gaps, but there is no one in the comment section that mentions it.